# Linux regex - remove "new line", but keep "CR + new line"?

Tags: regex, perl, vim, sed

cat -ev ./test.txt

```
1 line with "carriage return \r" and "new line \n"   ^M$
2 line only with "new line \n"   $
3  ^M$
4 line with "carriage return \r" and "new line \n"   ^M$
5 line with "carriage return \r" and "new line \n"   ^M$
6 line only with "new line \n"  $
7 line only with "new line \n"  $
8 line with "carriage return \r" and "new line \n"   ^M$
```

I would like to remove new line char \n, but **only in lines without CR**.

So output should be something like this:

```
1 line with "carriage return \r" and "new line \n"   ^M$
2 line only with "new line \n"   3  ^M$
4 line with "carriage return \r" and "new line \n"   ^M$
5 line with "carriage return \r" and "new line \n"   ^M$
6 line only with "new line \n"  7 line only with "new line \n"  8 line with "carriage return \r" and "new line \n"   ^M$
```

And after that, it`s time for removing CR.
Final output:

```
1 line with "carriage return \r" and "new line \n"   $
2 line only with "new line \n"   3  $
4 line with "carriage return \r" and "new line \n"   $
5 line with "carriage return \r" and "new line \n"   $
6 line only with "new line \n"  7 line only with "new line \n"  8 line with "carriage return \r" and "new line \n"   $
```

Last point is easy, for example in vim: **%s@\r@@gc** ... there is a lot of tips in internet "how to remove CR".

But my problem is with beginng - how to remove "\n" in perl and/or sed, but only with lines without CR ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do both steps at once in Perl:

```
perl -pe 's/(?<!\r)\n//; s/\r$//'
```

(Remove newline if not preceeded by carriage return; remove carriage return at end of line.)

Alternatively:

```
perl -pe 'chomp; s/\r\z/\n/'
```

(Remove trailing newline; replace final carriage return by newline.)

The first version can also be adapted to vim:

```
:%s/\r\@<!\n
:%s/\r$
```

(Disclaimer: I haven't tested this.)

Comment: @ikegami OP did say "Linux regex". :-)

Comment: I wasn't suggesting anything should be changed.

Comment: thanks, it`s working. Last question - do you know how to do it in vim ? :)
I have error:          E486: Pattern not found: (?<!\r)\n

Answer (score 2):

A solution with GNU awk (using the record separator):

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS="\r\n"}{gsub(/\n/,"")}1' test.txt
```

Comment: You should mention that's GNU awk only for multi-char RS.